# PHP generating and naming html for calendar to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I have a PHP page where a user can select a month and then an html label and selection box will generate for each day of the month:

```
<?php $i=1; while($i <= $daysInMonth){?>
    <table align="center" style="width: 435px">
        <tr>
            <td class="style1"><p><label id="Label1"><?php echo($month.' '.$i); ?></label>&nbsp;</p></td>
            <td class="style1"><p><?php echo($dropdown); ?></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php $i++; }?>
```

The selection boxes are filled with multiple names. The user will then select one or more names for each day of the month. I'm trying to figure out the best solution to match these names to the day of the month and get them into a MySQL database. I don't want to just have 31 $_POST['6'] submissions. I'm trying to think of a way to use arrays, but I'm struggling with determining how to keep names matched with the day of the month.

Should I use a multidimensional array? Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This leads to more questions:
* Is there a default name for each day?
* Is this default name very likely to be used often?
Depending on the answer, you might then prefer to send pair of [day,name indices] somehow, otherwise, you might prefer implicit day and send 28-31 list of indices of names (I say indices of names because it appears you are using preset names.)
Also, you have a mistake above, you ids have to be unique, so "Label1" violate that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map every day of the month to an unique field name. For instance, if you don't care about years, then you can map day 28 of month 11 to the unique field name "11-28", and look for the data in `$_POST["11-28"]`.

You can then write a loop that goes through all months and all days, and looks inside `$_POST` for the data you need.